# Dynamically resize Bootstrap panels on panel collapse/minimize

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, user-interface

I have a page where there are 3 panels adjacent to each other with width 4-4-4.

I am looking for a solution by which if any of the columns if minimized/collapsed.... then the other 2 panels could resize itself and take the space left behind by the collapsed panel and make their width 6-6.

Same again if of the remaining 2 panels if any of them if collapsed the left over panel should resize itself to take over the whole page 12.

Is there any javascript library available which gives me a optimum solution for this?

Comment: maybe this can help ?
http://www.bootply.com/RwnUXIcLap

Comment: @qballer I am not looking for draggable resize option... This i know is available in jquerry-ui functionality. 

My problem statement is when your panel have a minimize button which completely hides the panel and leaves the page with the other 2 panels.... In that condition the other 2 panels should resize themselves to utlize the complete page width.